# How to integrate Google Assistant service into my camera? We want to develop a camera with voice for commercial

Tags: camera, google-assistant-sdk

How to integrate Google Assistant service into my camera? We want to develop a camera with voice for commercial?

And "Warning: You can't launch commercial devices that integrate with the Google Assistant SDK. It's available for experimental and non-commercial uses only." in the document which the link is https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview, so we can't integrate Google Assistant service into my camera?

Comment: Looks like you've answered your own question there. Google does have a transcribe and tts api which I think their assistant makes use of so you could take that approach?

Comment: Hi,so means we cannot use Google Assistant service for commercial ?right?

Answer (score 0):

For integration into a camera, you actually want to look at developing a [Smart Home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview). This will enable you to integrate the Assistant into your camera. There is a [CameraStream trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream) and [Camera device type](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/camera) that will help you get started.